# Cannot retrieve mapping for action error - html:form

Tags: java, jsp, struts

In Struts 1.2, I am trying to create a new html:form.

```
<html:form action = "/doRequestCAP" style="display:inline;">
</html:form>
```

But I am getting this error when I try to load the page.

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve mapping for action /doRequestCAP
```

I checked my formatting for the action and form definitions and they look fine.

```
<form-bean name="requestCAPForm" type="project.web.RequestCAPForm"/>

<action path=/requestCAP"
type="project.RequestCAPAction"
name="requestCAPForm"
validate="true"
input="viewClaimants.do" //the page this form is on
scope="request"
>
<forward name="success" path="viewclaimants.do"/>
</action>
```

Both the requestCAPForm and RequestCAPAction java classes have been placed in the .web directory (currently they don't do anything) and are imported into the requestCAP.jsp class. I have tried multiple variations of declaring the action form to no avail, and cannot find a clear answer to what I'm doing wrong anywhere. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<action path=/requestCAP"` with `<action path="/doRequestCAP"`.